# Customize Header and Footer of XML Spreadsheet Schema Components

Tags: xml, excel, tags, schema, spreadsheet

I am trying to change the font size and location of the header and footer using the XML Spreadsheet schema as explained in this document:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx

I am using code to export data to an excel worksheet that will be printable without needing further adjustments. Below is the code for the header and footer:

```
<x:PageSetup>
<x:PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.4" x:Right=".5" x:Top".5"/>
<x:Header x:Margin="0.2"  Data="My Header"/>
<x:Footer x:Margin="0.2"  Data="My Footer"/>
</x:PageSetup>
```

It displays "My Header" and "My Footer" on the top and bottom, centered and in small font. I want it to be large font and aligned left. Is this possible?

If it is not possible, is there a way to change the height of the header and footer block? When I change the margin (for instance,  x:Margin="0.75"  ) the header ends up moving down but going behind the spreadsheet data text that is normally below it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the header/footer styling syntax can be found here: http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/SpreadsheetML/evenHeader.html

Eventually I got to this:

```
<x:Header 
x:Margin=".75" 
Data="&amp;C&amp;&quot;-,Bold&quot;&amp;25MY FIRST LINE&#10;MY SECOND LINE" />
```

This code is making the header Centered , Bold and size 25 on two lines.